# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3) in Python ARIMA implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, statsmodels, arima

I am trying to create an ARIMA model to predict stock market values (experimenting with this, not going to step on it to use it real life) and export it in PNG format for all the 512 stocks i have in my dataset. In the PNG it will be shown the Actual and the predicted value.

Error:

```
forecast, stderr, conf_int = model_fit.forecast(steps=len(X_test))   
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA

# Load Training and Test Data.
train_df = pd.read_csv(r'mypath\train.csv', parse_dates=['datetime'])
test_df = pd.read_csv(r'mypath\test.csv', parse_dates=['datetime'])

# Getting unique stock names.
stocks = train_df['Short Company Name'].unique()

# Create a directory to save pngs.
output_directory = r'ARIMAprediction'
os.makedirs(output_directory, exist_ok=True)

for stock in stocks:
    print(f"Processing Stock: {stock}")

    # Filter data for the current stock.
    train_stock = train_df[train_df['Short Company Name'] == stock]
    test_stock = test_df[test_df['Short Company Name'] == stock]

    # Extracting features (for this, all the dataset is used).
    features = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
    X_train, y_train = train_stock[features], train_stock['close']
    X_test, y_test = test_stock[features], test_stock['close']

    # Fit ARIMA model
    order = (5, 1, 2)  
    model = ARIMA(y_train, order=order)
    model_fit = model.fit()

    # Prediction.
    forecast, stderr, conf_int = model_fit.forecast(steps=len(X_test))
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please post the full error trace (and shave off any not-necessary code) - se how to create a [mre].

Comment: @desertnaut I Have added the total trace of the error. for the minimal reproducible example, i will need to read it carefully.

Comment: OK, but please notice that you were supposed to do this *before* posting...

Comment: `forecast` has only [one array_like return value](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.forecast.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.forecast-returns).

Comment: You need to pass error. `forecast, stderr, conf_int = model_fit.forecast(steps=len(X_test), alpha=0.05)`

Comment: @toyotaSupra still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`forecast` method](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.forecast.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.forecast) of your `model_fit` [`ARIMAResults` object](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.html) returns an `array_like` of length `steps`. Which is why it return too many values and can't unpack them into three variables.

To get confidence intervals you need to use the [`get_forecast` method](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.get_forecast.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.get_forecast) instead. statsmodel has some examples in [their documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_forecasting.html) that seem close to what you are trying to do. There is a [small section](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_forecasting.html#Specifying-the-number-of-forecasts) on the difference between `forecast` and `get_forecast`. There is also [a section](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_forecasting.html#Plotting-the-data,-forecasts,-and-confidence-intervals) showing how to plot the forecast and it's confidence interval with matplotlib.